# How to concatenate and print every element of the string?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, substring

```c
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    int ln = strlen (argv['\0']);
    int count = 0;
    char cipher_keyword [count+1];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 0,  n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++){
            cipher_keyword [j] = argv [i][j];
            printf("Cipher_keyword: %c\n", cipher_keyword [j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Cipher_keyword_outofLoop: %s\n", cipher_keyword);
    printf("\nCount of input string: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Input is:

`argv (file, arg1, arg2, arg3);`

For example:

`argv (file, abc defg hijkl)`

Now, when I print `cipher_keyword [j]` in the loop, I am getting each element of the string printed line by line (which is expected). I want this to be stored in `cipher_keyword`, and the `printf` command outside the loop should give me all of the elements in a single line without any spaces. But in the `printf` command outside the loop, `cipher_keyword` is giving me the result of `[str.length][j]`, i.e., `jijkl`.

How to do I make the `printf` command outside the loop print all the elements, i.e., `abcdefghijkl`?

Comment: Also I don't think you can do  int ln = strlen (argv['\0']); you should pass an int in the [] brackets like argv[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cipher_keyword` only has 1 `char` allocated for it. Your loop is overflowing the array. So your code has **undefined behavior**.

You need to loop through `argv` one time to calculate the total `count` needed, then allocate the array, then loop through `argv` again to fill the array.

When filling the array, you need to use a separate index counter to access the array elements correctly. You are using the inner loop's counter, which resets back to 0 on each command line parameter that is processed. So you are overwriting array elements.

You are also not telling `printf()` how many `char`s are actually available in `cipher_keyword` for printing, either by null-terminating `cipher_keyword`, or by passing `count` as a parameter to `printf()`. You must do one of those steps, or else `printf()` is likely to exceed the bounds of the array and print garbage from surrounding memory.

Try something more like this:

```c
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        count += strlen(argv[i]);
    }

    char cipher_keyword [count+1];

    count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++){
            cipher_keyword [count] = argv [i][j];
            printf("Cipher_keyword: %c\n", cipher_keyword [count]);
            ++count;
        }
    }

    cipher_keyword [count] = '\0';

    printf("Cipher_keyword_outofLoop: %s\n", cipher_keyword);
    // alternatively:
    // printf("Cipher_keyword_outofLoop: %.*s\n", count, cipher_keyword);

    printf("\nCount of input string: %d\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried running your code. But I am still getting the same answer, i.e., It is printing the characters of the last element only. I also tried your alternative code of printf, but still the same answer.

Comment: @Indu sorry, I left out an important detail. I have updated by answer.